# What do !punish and !forgive commands do on some hardcore Battlefield 3 servers?

Tags: battlefield-3

Playing on some Hardcore Battlefield 3 servers, if I get teamkilled by someone, I get a prompt to type either !punish or !forgive. What do these commands do to that teammate? I tried asking a few times in chat, but nobody ever answered me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

!punish and !forgive are commands added by plugins, and there are multiple plugins which add these commands.

In almost all cases, !forgive just means you ignore the violation, if it was unintentional.

One of the more common ones is [Insane Punisher](https://forum.myrcon.com/showthread.php?1069-Insane-Punisher) which uses !punish to kill the person who team killed you.  There are some plugins, however, which make !punish kick the person off the server.

Comment: And that's why Hardcore sucks. People jump around in front of you while you are firing and then have you punished even though it is their fault.

Comment: Wow, kick them? That's pretty extreme. Killing them is even better of a punishment than just kicking them from the server. They can re-join and all, but still, it just seems like it would be extreme to kick someone who simply teamkilled once in a long while.

I remember that some servers are set to auto-kick someone who teamkills a certain number of times (say 3) with one minute, or something like that; I find that acceptable, regardless to whether the teammate !forgives or !punishes. But allowing a teammate to get them kicked from an occasional team kill is a bit extreme.

Comment: do you know if there is any difference between `!forgive` and taking no action?

Comment: @vartec, I think !forgive is there so that if you're sure something was unintentional, you won't accidentally !punish for it later.

Comment: @agent86: ok, makes sense. I thought it might also vary on if TK counts towards TK/minute kick counter.